# RestKit memory warning when refetching entries

Tags: ios, rest, memory-leaks, restkit

When mapping a response for a second time RestKit keeps allocating memory without ever releasing it.

**Example**

Json:

```
// http://example.com/api/shop/
{
    {
       "id": 1, 
       "title": "some shop",
       "items": [
           {
              "id": 1,
              "name": "some item"
           },
           ... 
           {
              "id": 10000,
              "name": "some other item"
           }          
       ]
    }

 }
```

Response mapping/descriptors

```
let itemMapping = RKEntityMapping(forEntityForName: "Item", inManagedObjectStore: RKManagedObjectStore.defaultStore())
itemMapping.addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary([
        "title":"title",
        "id": "iID"
])
itemMapping.identificationAttributes = ["iID"]

let shopMapping = RKEntityMapping(forEntityForName: "Shop", inManagedObjectStore: RKManagedObjectStore.defaultStore())
shopMapping.addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary([
        "title":"title",
        "id": "sID"
])
shopMapping.identificationAttributes = ["sID"]

shopMapping.addPropertyMapping(RKRelationshipMapping(fromKeyPath: "items", toKeyPath: "items", withMapping: itemMapping))

let shopResponseDescriptor = RKResponseDescriptor(mapping: shopMapping, method: RKRequestMethod.Any, pathPattern: "/api/shop/", keyPath: nil, statusCodes: RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClass.Successful))



RKObjectManager.sharedManager().addResponseDescriptorsFromArray(
    [
        shopResponseDescriptor
    ]
)
```

This keeps allocating memory until the application crashes.

Using instruments I was able to determine that the app crashes when a little over 650mb has been allocated mostly consisting of:

1. `__NSDictionary`, size: 226mb, responsible caller: `[NSManagedObject dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:]`
2. `__NSSet`, size: 168mb, responsible caller: -`[RKManagedObjectMappingOperationDataSource mappingOperation:targetObjectForRepresentation:withMapping:inRelationship:]`
3. `__NSArray` size: 112mb, responsible caller: `-[RKManagedObjectMappingOperationDataSource mappingOperation:targetObjectForRepresentation:withMapping:inRelationship:]`

Even though a response usually won't contain that many objects which are already stored on the device in case many objects have been changed something like that could happen and crash the app. Has anybody run into this issue and is there a fix?

Comment: Your shop mapping has a typo (id instead of s_id) which would prevent the existing object from being found. Hard to say more than that without seeing more code and the model objects.

Comment: I edited my Question to fix the typo but this was only present here on SO and not in my test project. The model objects are simple NSManagedObjects I've created a test project + backend to test exactly this and confirm the issue

Comment: @matteok did you find a solution? I'm fighting with a same problem

Comment: Sadly no. I just started on that project again recently and thinking about migrating to Sync https://github.com/SyncDB/Sync to do CoreData mapping instead.